# How to display content as slide show in colorbox window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to output my images using the Colorbox plugin, but can't find right parameter to display as slides, with navigation,  it display my content as list

example:

```
var data= '
<p><a class="group4"  href="img1.jpg"></a></p>
<p><a class="group4"  href="img2.jpg"></a></p>
<p><a class="group4"  href="img3.jpg"></a></p>
';

$.colorbox({html:data, rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
```

Comment: cs you jsfiddle this? Do you have any errors output?  What is the problem?

Comment: Hi!, no errors,  now content displayed in colorbox dialig as list ->

line1
line2
line3

but, I need to display it as slides

Comment: I don't know why, but if I use this code in a separate file, all things work well, as expected. But  with drupal something goes wrong, and all other similar plugins (fancybox, lightbox, ...)  work fine, problem only with the colorbox

Comment: is it possible that you are trying to run the code BEFORE the colorbox code is loaded?  Is it (colorbox) loaded via ajax? Is $ referencing the same jquery or are you using multiple versions?